# How to convert MMSS and hundredths of seconds to seconds in a new DataFrame column

Tags: python, dataframe, beautifulsoup

The DataFrame is coming from a website via beautiful soup. This is what the dataframe looks like:

```
   Unnamed: 0              Name  G Total Time    Time/G
0           1              Army  7     272:03  38:51.86
1           2  Western Michigan  8     293:05  36:38.13
2           3         Air Force  8     292:09  36:31.13
3           4              Navy  8     285:33  35:41.63
4           5         Minnesota  8     285:23  35:40.38
```

I would like to create a new column `df_7['Second/G]` that converts the minutes and seconds from `df_7['Time/G']` to seconds.

The problem I am getting is that Pandas thinks that the minutes are hours and I am getting the following errors: `ParserError: hour must be in 0..23: 38:51.86`

This is the code that resulted in the error:

```
df_7['Time/G'] = df_7['Time/G'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df_7['Seconds/G'] = df_7['Time/G'].dt.total_seconds()
```

I tried converting df_7['Time/G'] to datetime but I think this is where the issues is. I am stumped as to how to resolve this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you just prepend `"0:"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepended the scraped data with '0:'. Then converted the column to `timedelta`. Finally, I created a new column that converts the minutes to seconds using `dt.total_seconds()`

```
df_7['Time/G'] = '0:' + df_7['Time/G'].astype(str)
df_7['Time/G'] = pd.to_timedelta(df_7['Time/G'])
df_7['Seconds/G'] = df_7['Time/G'].dt.total_seconds().astype(float)
df_7
```

Help from: https://blog.duaneleem.com/converting-time-to-seconds-or-minutes-for-an-entire-python-dataframe-csv-column/